# Interface working on activity but not in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, interface, android-vision

I have used a solution from the SO accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35287835/detect-and-capture-barcode-automatically-when-it-is-read-by-camera/42932521).
It works well inside an `Activity` but when I implement it inside a `Fragment`, I got the following error:

> Exception thrown from receiver.java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.example.app.MainActivity cannot be cast to
>   com.example.app.QRCodeDetectedInterface at
>   com.example.app.BarcodeGraphic.(OcrGraphic.java:54) at
>   com.example.app.OcrDetectorProcessor.receiveDetections(OcrDetectorProcessor.java:49)

It seems there is a problem implementing the interface inside the `Fragment`. How to overcome this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In link you provided **BarcodeCaptureActivity** listens to events. In your case, as exception suggests, **MainActivity** listens to events. Your **com.example.app.MainActivity** must implement **com.example.app.QRCodeDetectedInterface**.

Comment: I implemented on MainActivity and it worked. Thanks.